# How to get rid off Grey bar in Libre Office?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

While Copying some texts from Internet to Libre Office a grey bar appears as like that screenshot that i have attached, why so?

How to eliminate this ?

What is the reason of that? I'm using Libre Office 5 in Ubuntu 14.04.
[image: Libre Office Writer Grey]

Comment: Could you provide a link to the text being copied?

Comment: I could not get u !! @UniformsForSale

Comment: I believe that the marks are to indicate a character that acts like a space, but is not the space character itself, like a non-breaking space or a line feed.

Comment: You would remove them the same way as any other character, with the Delete key, then you can type in anything you want, including a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all these grey things simultanously:

1. Copy one of these grey bars.
2. Press Ctrl+H
3. On the appeared window of Find - Replace paste the grey bar to the space for "Find"
4. On the space for "Replace" just type an empty space with Space button.
5. Press on the button "Replace All"

Comment: Happy to see this. Thanks @ Muzaffar. and any alternate way u found to get rid off this means let me know.

Comment: Another option is copying as a plain text. There are extensions of browsers or you may copy the text first to gedit, then to Libre Writer.

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks. I always do. but i feel that , some of the data can't able to copy in Gedit like Pic, is that so? @ Muzaffar

Comment: Yes, you can only copy text. Tables, pics, drawings - they are uncopiable.

Answer (score 1):

In order not to apply the formatting of a HTML page you can use the insert function <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Paste Special…</kbd> or the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.

You will see the dialog below. Select <kbd>Unformatted Text</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"Copy one of these grey bars." --> Already too much work.

Look, Just click to the 'View' dropdown, and untick the "Field Shadings" checkbox.
Not sure why it's checked by default, but that gets rid of the dumb grey formatting junk.